# How can I retrieve the last record inserted into a Java Hashtable data structure?

Tags: java, data-structures, hashtable

I have the following problem working on a Java application that uses an **Hashtable calcoliTable** data structure.

This is the content of my **calcoliTable**:

```
{
FITTIZIO-2015=CalcoloValoreDellaGSBean [data=2015-11-27, maturato=249540.544989802560000, sommaMaturatoMovimento=249540.544989802560000], 

1=CalcoloValoreDellaGSBean [data=2015-11-27, maturato=249540.544989802560000, sommaMaturatoMovimento=249540.544989802560000]
}
```

As you can see it contains 2 entries having **id=1** and **id=FITTIZIO-2015**.

I want to retrieve the entry that was inserted most recently(that should be the one having **id=FITTIZIO-2015**).

I have tried to do in this way:

```
CalcoloValoreDellaGSBean calcoloPrecedente = (CalcoloValoreDellaGSBean) calcoliTable.get(calcoliTable.size())
```

But it won't work because in this way it is searching the entry having **id=2**.

How can I retrieve the last entry inserted into my **HashTable**? Exist a way to do it without using explitelly the key?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LinkedHashMap` with an access-order ordering mode :

```
Map<KeyType,ValueType> map = new LinkedHashMap<KeyType,ValueType> (16, 0.75F, true);
```

And then

```
map.entrySet().iterator().next()
```

will give you the last entry you accessed (either inserted or retrieved).

Comment: I think, the problem is OP supports legacy code and can't change a data structure.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko That may be the case, but it's not stated in the question.

Comment: Also be aware that LinkedHashMap is NOT synchronized which Hashtable is so synchronizing externally may be required.

Comment: @bradimus Oops. Forgot the `iterator()`. Thanks!

Comment: OP wants to access the entry "inserted most recently", not the last accessed one (from the LinkedHashMap javadoc: accessOrder : the ordering mode - true for access-order, false for insertion-order). Here i think you need to use false, and access the last element of the iterator. Not really effective.

Comment: @Thierry Well, it depends how this Map is used. If there are only inserts prior to the OPs attempt to get the last inserted entry, access-order would give the last inserted entry first.

Comment: Certainly. But it is an edge behavior, and will reduce the maintainability of the software. What happens if in six months someone else adds reading inside the map in between (and reading in a map is expected to be side-effect free by almost anybody) ? What was sold as a solution to get the last inserted data, was in fact a solution to get last accessed data. The poor guy adding the new code will break some completely unrelated code, and i can assure you that he will curse you ;)